# Вопрос про Google Test, синглтоны и инициализацию/финализацию

Tags: c++, gtest

У меня есть пара вопросов про библиотеку модульного тестирования `Google Tests`.

1. Допустим, есть глобальный объект со статической продолжительностью хранения. Например, это синглтон. Я не совсем понимаю, как отдельные тесты взаимодействуют с таким объектом. Будет ли такой синглтон разделяться между тестами точно так же, как между обыкновенными функциями? Или же тестовый фреймворк каким-то образом выдает каждому тесту свою копию глобального статического объекта?
2. Если я хочу перед началом всех тестов выполнить глобальную инициализацию чего-то (той же сетевой подсистемы), а после завершения всех тестов - глобальную финализацию, то каким образом я должен это делать в рамках `Google Tests`? Если я пробую сделать эти действия до и после `InitGoogleTest()/RUN_ALL_TEST()`, то по какой-то причине `Visual Studio` перестает видеть все наборы тестов проекта.

Comment: глобальный объект со статической продолжительностью хранения != синглтон, Ну разве что если кто-то наговнокодил синглетон Меерса.

Comment: Дело не только в синглтонах Мейерса. Вопрос так же касается статичных классов (все члены - статичные).

Answer (score 1):

Для использования некоторого предварительно изготовленного состояния в тесте следует создать fixture:

```
class TestFixture: public ::testing::Test
{
    public: explicit TestFixture(void)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public: ~TestFixture(void) override noexcept
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected: void SetUp(void) override // вызывается после конструктора перед тестом
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected: void TearDown(void) override // вызывается после теста перед деструктором
    {
        // ...
    }

    public: void DoSomething(void)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

А потом использовать его объявляя тесты с помощью макроса `TEST_F`, первым параметром которого является имя класса fixture:

```
TEST_F(TestFixture, MyTest)
{
    DoSomething(); // поля и методы TestFixture доступны через this
}
```

Важно отметить, что объект fixture для каждого теста пересоздается заново.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что фиксации лишь позволяют автоматизировать однотипную инициализацию/финализацию, однако не решают проблему с наличием глобального состояния, которое, например, вызвано наличием библиотеки логирования, которая инициализируется при запуске приложения и финализируется при его завершении?

Comment: И еще мне не совсем понятно, как реализован запуск выполнения тестов в параллельном режиме. Например, если тесты используют одни и те же данные со статической продолжительностью хранения и глобальной видимостью.

Comment: @MGNeo Филисофия gtest такова, что каждый тест должен начинаться с чистого листа. Хотя при желании конечно можно сделать что-то в main. Если тесты используют какие-то данные со статической продолжительностью хранения и глобальной видимостью, то эти данные должны быть constexpr. Параллельный запуск тестов выполняет их в разных процессах.